# Prove that then $A$ and $B$ are similar operators.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finitedimensional vector space and let $ A, B \in L(V) $ be linear operators and $e, f$ ordered bases of $V$ so  that for their matrix representations in said bases $$ A(e) =B(f) $$. Prove that then $A$ and $B$ are similar operators.
This seems pretty trivial to me, as
$$ B(f)={I} ^{-1} * A(e) * I $$. So that would be the proof? I'm actually interested if I understoodd the definiton of similar operators correctly, do I just look at matrices of the operators and prove that they are similar?

Comment: In my class we defined them as matrices of linear operators, that is the representation of an operator in form of a matrix, not sets.

Comment: I edited it in the question so that it is clear

Comment: Oh, ok, I got confused then. I just never seen anybody writing representation matrices like this. I'm used to $[A]_e$.

Comment: Still, I think there is a problem in your solution. I guess when you wrote $I$ you took the identity matrix as a representation matrix from a base to itself, for example the base $e$. Then what you proved is that $A$ is similar to the operator where $B(f)$ is the representation matrix in the base $e$. This is not what you want to prove, because the operator $B$ has $B(f)$ as representation matrix with the base $f$. So instead of $I$ you should take a matrix $J$ which is the representation matrix of the identity operator from base $f$ to base $e$.